# Delete row if exists

Tags: mysql, joomla

```
DELETE IF EXIST `#__menu`.*
FROM `#__menu` 
LEFT JOIN `#__extensions` ON `#__extensions`.`name` = 'com_view' 
WHERE `#__menu`.`component_id` = `#__xtensions`.`extension_id`
AND `#__menu`.`alias` = 'view-sites' AND `#__menu`.`path` = 'view-sites' AND `#__menu`.`title` = 'View sites';
```

What is wrong in my sql? I think the problem is in `IF EXIST`, but i could not figure out how to use it on row.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you're deleting rows from a table, you don't need to use `IF EXISTS` - you're using a `WHERE` clause, so if it exists - it will be deleted.

Try changing your query to:

```
DELETE
FROM `#__menu` 
LEFT JOIN `#__extensions` ON `#__extensions`.`name` = 'com_view' 
WHERE `#__menu`.`component_id` = `#__xtensions`.`extension_id`
AND `#__menu`.`alias` = 'view-sites' AND `#__menu`.`path` = 'view-sites' AND `#__menu`.`title` = 'View sites';
```

Also, you don't need to specify ```#__menu``` .*`` (the columns) to be deleted - you'll just need ```DELETE FROM...`. Check out [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) for more info regarding the syntax.

Comment: but there can be null (just no extension yet with this id)

Comment: You have `WHERE component_id = extension_id`, it shouldn't be able to return any missing records from `#__menu` or `#__extensions` with that clause; to be on the safe-side, however, you could either change it from a `LEFT JOIN` to a regular `JOIN`, *or* you could add `component_id IS NOT NULL` (and/or) `extension_id IS NOT NULL` to your `WHERE` clause

Comment: @Kirix sure thing; Keep me posted and I'll try to help out if it doesn't work =]